# How to change Panel Size in mozilla like chrome extension

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**Panel Size is fixed in SDK-based Add-on**

I want to change the size of panel automatically like chrome dictionary extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dictionarycom-extension/epkhgmlgiomobdlofllfmoejgjdojknn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

If you will search in panel it will show big and small data like content requirement.
In Mozilla panel we can fix only 1 type of size like `width:400px` and `height:400px` etc. but i want that panel size should based on data size means like chrome extensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this in the Add-on SDK with a little extra code.

In main.js:

```
var panel = require("panel").Panel({
  contentURL: "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK",
  onShow: function() {
        let worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: [
                data.url('windowsize.js')
            ]
        });

        worker.port.on('winsize', function(data) {
            panel.resize((data.width-120), (data.height-120));
        });
        worker.port.emit('fetchwinsize');
  }
});
```

In the content script:

```
self.port.on('fetchwinsize', function() {
    self.port.emit("winsize", {height: window.innerHeight, width: window.innerWidth});
});
```

Here's a working example of this:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/150225/latest/

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dictionary-extension/?src=ss        This is the add-on where i want panel on toolbarbutton but not the same size always. how can be this  possible.