# Making Firefox SDK panel fit on every apperance

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a Firefox extension using the SDK, and having trouble making a pop up at the right size. I'm making use of the examples at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_toggle#Attaching_panels_to_buttons) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14129558/239003) to make something similar to the example shown in that section of the MDN page.

The panel I made is a little small the first time opened (it scrolls vertically), but I'm more confused by the changing heights each time opened.

My panel has HTML code like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
            <ul id="links">
                    <li id="menu1">Menu1 text</li>
                    <li id="menu2">Menu2 text</li>
                    <li id="menu3">Menu3 text</li>
            </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my `index.js`, I create the panel with the following:

```
var button = ToggleButton({
        id: "name-of-extension",
        label: "Label text",
        icon: './icon.svg',
        onChange: handleToggleButton
});
var button_panel = Panel({
        contentURL: './popup_interface.html',
        contentScriptFile: ['./script-for-onclicks.js', './windowsize.js'],
        onHide: handleHidePanel,
        onShow: function() {
            button_panel.port.emit('fetchwinsize');
        }
});
button_panel.port.on('winsize', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        button_panel.resize(data.width, data.height);
});
function handleToggleButton(state) {
        if (state.checked) {
                button_panel.show({
                        position: button
                });
        } else {
                button_panel.hide();
                handleHidePanel();
        }
}
function handleHidePanel() {
        button.state("window", {checked: false});
}
```

Where `windowsize.js` has the following:

```
self.port.on('fetchwinsize', function() {
        let listElement = document.getElementById("links");
        self.port.emit("winsize", {height: listElement.scrollHeight, width: listElement.scrollWidth});
});
```

Repeatedly opening the panel (by clicking the togglebutton) changes the dimensions in ways I don't understand:

```
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
console.log: vanir: {"height":48,"width":304}
console.log: vanir: {"height":48,"width":272}
console.log: vanir: {"height":48,"width":240}
console.log: vanir: {"height":48,"width":208}
console.log: vanir: {"height":64,"width":176}
console.log: vanir: {"height":64,"width":144}
console.log: vanir: {"height":96,"width":129}
```

The size stays constant at 96x129 after that, needing to scroll horizontally and vertically (although the word-wraping causes the scrolling vertically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed William Bamberg to obtain the source for the MDN example, and he realized the problem.

In case anyone tries to do this too, the problem is that the panel's total size (including paddings and margins) are being set to the list element's size, which squeezes the list element each time.

Fixing this turned out to be a relatively easy CSS change:

```
html, body, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```